# How can I use APP_INITIALIZER in a nx library?

Tags: angular, nrwl

I've got an nx app shell that uses a primary view library, and this library depends on services that require initialization prior to first use. If I were in native Angular, I'd use APP_INITIALIZER and then my provider would pause during bootstrap, but my libs don't *have* a bootstrap.

I can't just move the service to the top-level app and have this work, can I? The service won't be seen by the lower-level modules properly. What's the best approach here?

EDIT: Since somebody asked, my final result...

I couldn't use APP_INITIALIZER in the library, but I only needed a thin wrapper in the app before deferring to code from the library.

From `@NGModule`...

```
providers: [{ 
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
    useFactory: authentication_preload, 
    deps: [AuthenticationService], 
    multi: true 
},...]
```

And then that referenced factory...

```
export function authentication_preload(authService: AuthenticationService) {
  return () => authService.initialize();
}
```

`AuthenticationService` was imported without any fanfare from one of the libraries I loaded, and `initialize` returned a promise that handled everything I wanted done and resolved once it was ready. End result: Application boot couldn't continue until the auth service was ready to work with the interceptors.

Comment: Is your library an Angular library? By my experience APP_INITIALIZER works in angular library (v6). Although so far I am only able to make it work when the service is registered in library module, not the way inside `@Injectable()` decorator. Which means I'm getting warnings about circular dependency, but it works.

Comment: How did you manage it atlast?